# Creating an .sty file that is equivalent to \input{file}?

Tags: package-writing, anki

I'm trying to get the flashcard program `Anki` to accept my LaTeX shortcuts that I always include in the preamble through `\input{...}`. It seems like the software has now forbidden this practice as you can share you card decks with other people, so you could trick someone to reveal files.

Anyway, since I can do a `\usepackage` in the preamble I would need to create an `.sty` file, such that including it is equivalent to having the line

```
\input{</path/to/file>}
```

in the preamble. How can I do this, since I've never looked into the format of `.sty` files?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The only special thing about `.sty` files is really that `@` is allowed as a character in command names, without having to write `\makeatletter...\makeatother`.  So rename your input file to `myfile.sty` and try `\usepackage{myfile}`.  If you need more help then please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what problems you encounter.

Comment: @AndrewSwann **That's an over-simplification!** You for instance at least need `\ProvidesPackage`. And even then, there are some standards on how should the package codes look like.

Comment: @tohecz I konw, but it may be good enough for this use-case.

Comment: OK, so what is the shortest .sty file that does an \input{file}? I don't want to rename the file, since the file is already \input by every latex document that I've written. I also don't want a copy, because I then have to update two files whenever I add something to it.

Comment: @tohecz You probably _should_ have many things, but none are _required_ for a `.sty` to work.

Comment: @tohecz: Unless the OP does not want to publish his macro pool package it's okay to drop such stuff as the usual package headers and potential options

Comment: @eof: the shortest way in my point of view is just to put `\input{file}` in a file called `mypackage.sty`, for more 'security' say `\InputIfFileExists{file}{}{}`. Store the file in a folder which is searched by LaTeX

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Wanna make that an answer?

Comment: @eof Are there any news here? Can you elaborate a bit on the matter or can you even provide a self-answer by now?