# Autocomplete not working when loading Biblatex in *.sty file

Tags: biblatex, packages, auto-completion

For clarity reasons I want to outsource all my packages in a `packages.sty` and all my commands in a `commands.sty`.

I can now call them by running

```tex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{packages} % contains \usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{commands} % contains \addbibresource{sources.bib}

\begin{document}
....
```

Almost everything works as intended but autocomplete / IntelliSense for Biblatex do not work in any editor.
Citations work fine but neither TexStudio nor VSCode show available sources.

### Workaround

Changing file names to `.tex` and calling via `\input{packages}` does work.
I'm simply curious why it does not work with `*.sty` files.

Comment: ... nothing to do with us. Although this is indeed a "tool related to TeX", it's simply something that particular IDE does not implement, you can try asking them for a feature request.

Comment: By the way the proper way to "usepackage" inside a sty file is `RequirePackage`.

Comment: From the TeX point of view the only differences are https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215402/creating-an-sty-file-that-is-equivalent-to-inputfile#comment505626_215402